# NodeJS SockeIO basic problem with emitting

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So I'm trying to build a chat application with SocketIO. However, I don't understand most of the code in the SocketIO tutorial, specifically the JQuery parts. I'm just not familiar. I thought it wouldn't be too hard, but I've hit a wall on the emit() function. My script seems to work up till that point.

Here is the client code

```
script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
            var socket = io();
            const chatbox = document.getElementById('n');
            const d = document.getElementById('m');
            function sender(){
                var message = chatbox.value;
                socket.emit('chat message',message);
            }
            socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
                d.appendChild($('<div>').text(msg));
            });
            const b = document.querySelector('#clicker');
            b.addEventListener('click',sender);
    </script>
```

and here is the relevant server code

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connection logged');
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
```

Not sure why the emit fails in the client. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, can you check if your socket actually connected via `socket.connected` after `var socket = io();` maybe a console would work `console.log(socket.connected)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone watching, I figured it out by rewriting the existing working SocketIO code into my own. Here's the solution
Client side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
            const socket = io();
            const chatbox = document.getElementById('n');
            const d = document.getElementById('messages');
            function sender(){
                var message = chatbox.textContent;
                socket.emit('chat message',message);
            }
            socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
                const t = document.createElement('li');
                t.textContent = msg;
                d.appendChild(t);
            });
            const b = document.querySelector('#clicker');
            b.addEventListener('click',sender);
     </script>
```

and server

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
```